# elements with the same class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, getelementsbyclassname, classname

Im new to javascript because I skipped it and jumped to jquery and now Im writing a javascript code but I'm having trouble. I have multiple elements with the same class name and below each element is an a-tag. i want to hide/show the element upon clicking the button below it. How can i do this in javascript? (no jquery please).
HTML

```
<div>
 <div class="content">content 1</div>
 <a class="show-more" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="content">content 2</div>
 <a class="show-more" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="content">content 3</div>
 <a class="show-more" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
 display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
  var status = "less";
  function toggleText1() {
    if (status == "less") {
      document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementsByClassName("show-more")[0].innerText = "See Less";
      status1 = "more";
    } else if (status1 == "more") {
      document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementsByClassName("show-more")[0].innerText = "See More";
      status1 = "less";
    }   
  }
```

in my original code i named my content as content1,content2 and my a-tag as show-more1,show-more2 then my functions as toggleText1,toggleText2 and so on. It works but i find it inefficient. Can you guys guide me to the right path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one of methods how to solve it. Catch all the links, then use `Array#forEach` to iterate over them and bind `click` event to every element. Then find the `div` element in the parent node and toggle it's class from hidden to visible.

**ES6** solution.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");

Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].classList.toggle('hidden');
}));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">content 1</div>
  <a class="show-more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="content">content 2</div>
  <a class="show-more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="content">content 3</div>
  <a class="show-more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
```

**ES5** solution.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].classList.toggle('hidden');
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">content 1</div>
  <a class="show-more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="content">content 2</div>
  <a class="show-more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="content">content 3</div>
  <a class="show-more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Should note that this requires the use of es6+

Comment: @Ju66ernaut *How can i do this in javascript?* - isn't ES6 Javascript?

Comment: Indeed it is. However it is STILL not used by everyone who uses javascript. I am pointing it out because the OP does not use any es6+ syntax in his code

Comment: @Ju66ernaut Don't you think that it's **modern** enough that everyone should use it? And by the way - what do you think, should I teach OP some old and probably soon deprecated methods or try to make him friendly with the newest JS patterns?

Comment: It should be used by now, but it still doesn't have 100% support across all browsers. I am merely trying to point something out to the OP so he/she understands this may not work out of the box for them. It is not an affront to your answer.

Comment: @Ju66ernaut Fine, my friend.

Comment: tnx for the quick response. interesting answer, very short and its working. might need some explanation though, sorry I'm new in javascript. I noticed that you used children[0], will it still work if i have 2 or more contents above my div.content element?

Comment: @SGventra I've edited my answer, so it will work every time.

Comment: @JonP Yeah, but you know. OP didn't ask for performance on **every** browser available. Anyways - IE is almost dead.

Comment: But it's not dead yet and IE 11 still has a 3.6% global usage, more than Edge, so that is not an insignificant number of users. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). Personally, I would supply your modern version and a "classic" version so the OP can decide on what he want's to support.

Comment: @JonP I've added a solution which will work like everywhere.

Comment: @Kinduser i like the use of this. so, i prefer your es5 solution its more clearer to me. been wanting to use $(this) from jquery just dont know how to do it in javascript. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can pass the element in the onclick by using the this as the argument/parameter to know the source of the on click. Then you get the parent and get the correct content div and use the style element and to do some logic on what to display or hide.

And according to your post, you should also make your content divs hidden by default.

```js
function toggleText(aTag) {
  var content = aTag.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  if(content.style.display == null || content.style.display == "none")
  {
    content.style.display = 'block';
    aTag.innerText = "See Less";
  }
  else
  {
    content.style.display = 'none';
    aTag.innerText = "See More";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="content" style="display:none;">content 1</div>
 <a class="show-more" onclick="toggleText(this);" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="content" style="display:none;">content 2</div>
 <a class="show-more" onclick="toggleText(this);" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="content" style="display:none;">content 3</div>
 <a class="show-more" onclick="toggleText(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
</div>
```

also is it just me, or that just smells like a homework?

Comment: well, I'm remodelling a page for ebay and since ebay doesn't quite support jquery in its iframe so im trying to do some functions through javscript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hidePrev = function(event){
  element = event.target;
  element.previousSibling.previousSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">content 1</div>
  <a class="show-more" onclick='hidePrev(event);'
  href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="content">content 2</div>
  <a class="show-more"  onclick='hidePrev(event);'
  href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="content">content 3</div>
  <a class="show-more"  onclick='hidePrev(event);'
  href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a delegated event listener, which is an event listener assigned to a common ancestor element.

Check to see if the element is the type of element we are looking for (this check will probably change based on the actual content of the page), then select the previous element sibling and change the display property and text based on the current values.

This example uses a fat arrow function (introduced in the ECMAScript 2015 language specification), but a normal function expression would suffice if supporting old browsers is required.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const element = event.target
  if(event.target.classList.contains("toggle")) {
    const previous = event.target.previousElementSibling
    const text = element.textContent
    element.textContent = element.dataset.toggleText || "Show less"
    element.dataset.toggleText = text
    previous.classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="content hidden">content 1</div>
 <a class="toggle" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="content hidden">content 2</div>
 <a class="toggle" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="content hidden">content 3</div>
 <a class="toggle" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Crazy, CSS Only Answer** - for fun and educational purposes only

This does have *some* practical application, you could pre-open one of your content areas by adding a hash to the url. E.g http://yourdomain/page#Content2

```css
.content .show-less {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

#content-container .content:target {
  display: block;
}

#content-container .content:target~.show-more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container">
  <div>
    <div class="content" id="Content1">content 1 <a href="#content-container" class="show-less">Show Less</a></div>
    <a class="show-more" href="#Content1">Show more</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="content" id="Content2">content 2 <a href="#content-container" class="show-less">Show Less</a></div>
    <a class="show-more" href="#Content2">Show more</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="content" id="Content3">content 3 <a href="#content-container" class="show-less">Show Less</a></div>
    <a class="show-more" href="#Content3">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

More Reading:

- [Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)
- [Target Pseudo Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

Comment: thanks for the nice concept in css. my only problem with this is having to change the elements id everytime.